# redirecting url containing specific string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all urls that contain a specific string. The urls look like this

```
http://www.domain/com/modules.php?name=Kalender&op=list&d=8&m=6&y=2034
```

I have to redirect all urls that contain

```
name=Kalender&
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/kalender/
```

I tried several rules in my .htaccess. None of them worked:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} name=Kalender&
RewriteRule .* kalender

RewriteRule ^(.)name=Kalender&(.)$ http://www.domain.com/kalender/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/name=Kalender&/i$ http://www.domain.com/kalender/ [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} name=Kalender&
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/kalender/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=Kalender&
RewriteRule ^name=Kalender& http://www.domain.com/kalender/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)name=Kalender&(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/kalender/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/modules.php?name=Kalender&$

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/kalender [R=301,L]
```

This is the WordPress .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=Kalender(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /kalender/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I would like to add a 301. Is the the correct syntax? RewriteRule ^ /kalender/? [L,R=301]